# Zero downtime NServiceBus upgrades

Tags: nservicebus

Zero-downtime upgrades to an NServiceBus installation has been alluded to by Udi and Andreas a few times.  What is the correct approach to performing a zero-downtime upgrade to an NServiceBus installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this means is that since NSB is using messaging as an underlying transport, you can spin down your endpoints and data will still be received.  Assuming that the upgrade has not broken the message contract, you can then start the endpoints back up and there will be no downtime, only a delay in processing for the time of the upgrade.

Message contracts can be versioned in a backwards compatible way, you need to be sure to use interfaces for messages and follow the [guidance for versioning](http://docs.particular.net/samples/versioning/) message contracts.

(Added by Udi)

There is also the side-by-side deployment of NServiceBus.Host.exe that allows you to run two versions of the same process, both feeding off of the same queue at the same time. In this model, you can eliminate the delay in processing which can be very important in environments where you have strict service level agreements.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that's what I'd thought it was but wanted to check.  Have myself experienced the joy of receiving an order whilst upgrading my endpoints.  Quite an awesome experience!

Comment: Udi - so, would an example of the side-by-side deployment be having services named MyService.v1.0 and MyService.v1.1 that contain my v1.0 and v1.1 handlers?  Are there any examples of this that you are aware of?  Thanks, Sean.